# how to union 2 tables but select values based on condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

there are 2 tables - book, supply.
the supply table:

| supply_id | title | author | price | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | author1 | 518.99 | 2 |
| 2 | title2 | author2 | 570.20 | 6 |
| 3 | title3 | author3 | 540.50 | 7 |
| 4 | title4 | author4 | 360.80 | 3 |

the book table:

| book_id | title | author | price | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Мастер и Маргарита | Булгаков М.А. | 670.99 | 3 |
| 2 | Белая гвардия | Булгаков М.А. | 540.50 | 5 |
| 3 | Идиот | Достоевский Ф.М. | 460.00 | 10 |
| 4 | Братья Карамазовы | Достоевский Ф.М. | 799.01 | 3 |
| 5 | Игрок | Достоевский Ф.М. | 480.50 | 10 |
| 6 | Стихотворения и поэмы | Есенин С.А. | 650.00 | 15 |

I need to union them but only select those rows that have higher price.

```
select title, price, amount 
from supply  a1
union all
select title, price, amount 
from book a2
where a1.price > a2.price
```

Comment: In case of items that exist in both tables then take the one with the highest price, is that what you want?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes sir

Comment: Is table `Book` a superset of `Supply`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos no those are different tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select title, price, amount 
from supply s
where not exists (select 1 from book b where s.title = b.title and b.price > s.price)

union all

select title, price, amount 
from book b
where not exists (select 1 from supply s where s.title = b.title and s.price > b.price)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select bs.*
from (select bs.*,
             row_number() over (partition by title order by price desc) as seqnum
      from ((select supply_id, title, author, price, amount
             from book
            ) union all
            (select supply_id, title, author, price, amount
             from supply
            )
           ) bs
     ) bs
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: hmmm thx u, but this seems to be complicated, is there way to use where clause?